# Why is Async token function error triggered in azure Webjob (Nodejs) but not in local?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, async-await, azure-webjobs

I have developed a nodejs script to perform certain action in background and i want to trigger the nodejs as webjob in azure and schedule it. I tried to run the program in Local and it works perfectly fine.When i upload and run on azure webjob it triggers the following error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token function" referring to async funtion. The Program contains async function with proper awaits.Why is not allowing me to  run the script in azure webjob but in local.What might be solution for this.

NodeJs Version Local :8.9.4

```
[10/21/2018 22:30:17 > 0d2216: ERR ] async function ProcessWhatgroupSerial(Groups) { 
[10/21/2018 22:30:17 > 0d2216: ERR ] ^^^^^^^^ 
[10/21/2018 22:30:17 > 0d2216: ERR ] SyntaxError: Unexpected token function 
[10/21/2018 22:30:17 > 0d2216: ERR ] at Module._compile (module.js:439:25) 
[10/21/2018 22:30:17 > 0d2216: ERR ] at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10) 
[10/21/2018 22:30:17 > 0d2216: ERR ] at Module.load (module.js:356:32) 
[10/21/2018 22:30:17 > 0d2216: ERR ] at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) 
[10/21/2018 22:30:17 > 0d2216: ERR ] at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10) 
[10/21/2018 22:30:17 > 0d2216: ERR ] at startup (node.js:119:16) 
[10/21/2018 22:30:17 > 0d2216: ERR ] at node.js:935:3 
[10/21/2018 22:30:17 > 0d2216: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed 
[10/21/2018 22:30:17 > 0d2216: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code 8
```

Comment: `NodeJs Version Local :8.9.4` - that's useful, but what would be more useful would be to know what the version of NodeJS is where you **get the error**?

Answer (score 0):

The Nodejs version configured in Azure was 0.10 I had to update it to the latest stable version and it worked fine.

Comment: `was very old` is that a technical term?

Comment: How did you update it?